# PHP POST (i've seen all of post problems on dis site but they didn't helped)

Tags: php, post, size, getimagesize

hi guys i got problem with POST in php as u know,so ya, dats ma code

```
<form action="index.php?upload=true" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="upload image">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="DO IT"/>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['upload'])) {
    runMyFunction();
}
function runMyFunction(){
    $uploaded=$_POST['photo'];
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploaded);
    echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
    echo "height: " .  $height;
}
?>
```

so my problem is: when i press upload button, i get errors: 
http://postimg.org/image/h39bvyt8j/ (i cant upload images i dont have reputation)
and yes, all i need is: when i press upload button, image scale has to be written, as u see at the bottom of picture, for eg: i uploaded image, pressed uplaod and it wrote: Width:100px height: 150px
thanks for any help!(i think there is something with Post method)

Comment: you are using `$_GET` when you should be using `$_POST` in your `if (isset($_POST['upload'])){` also missing `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: You first have to upload file on your server than giving that uploaded file path in your `list($width, $height) = getimagesize($filepath);` you can get the right values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add

```
  enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

in the form and leave action blank. After that, add following code

```
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

 runMyFunction();
 }
 function runMyFunction(){
 $uploaded=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploaded);
 list($width, $height) = getimagesize($uploaded);
 echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
 echo "height: " .  $height;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you upload file you must define **enctype="multipart/form-data"** as :

```
<form action="index.php?upload=true" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="upload image">
    <input type="submit" name="upload" value="DO IT"/>
</form>
```

[Documentation is here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Should be using `$_FILES['photo']` instead of `$_POST['photo']` which means that you also need to add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to your `form` element.

Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(isset($_GET['upload']))
```

to

```
if(isset($_POST['uploaded']))
```

Also

```
$uploaded=$_POST['photo'];
```

to

```
 $uploaded = $_FILES['photo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Leave the `action = ""` empty since the code is present on the same file.

2)  Add the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the form tag.

3)  Use `$_FILES[];` instead of `$_POST[];`

4) Add the `['name']` next to `['photo']`

And Tadah! this should work now:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photo" id="photo" value="upload image">
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="DO IT"/>
</form>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {

runMyFunction();
}
function runMyFunction(){
$uploaded=$_FILES['photo']['name'];
list($width, $height) = getimagesize("path/to/images/image.jpg");
echo "width: " . $width . "<br />";
echo "height: " .  $height;
}
?>
```

Comment: hey thanks for ur answer but i get this error: ( ! ) Warning: getimagesize(path/to/images/image.jpg): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 12

Comment: @user3312564 Ahh, you need to specify the path of _your_ image there, what I wrote was just a dummy